# Remove left characters SSRS report expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Invoice number beginning with `INV`, but without the `INV` prefix.

My task is not to show the `INV` prefix in my report file. The current expression in SSRS is `=First(Fields!InvoiceNumber.Value, "InvoiceDataSet")`.

I was wondering if there is a condition I could add in SSRS or change the expression to hide or not show the `INV`, however show the rest of the number i.e. to remove strings?

Trying to do something like `=Left(Fields!InvoiceNumber.Value, len(Fields!InvoiceNumber.Value)-3) "InvoiceDataSet")`

[image]

Comment: I know it is not always possible.. but try and do as much of your data manipulation in SQL and let SSRS do the presentation ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your almost there. Change `LEFT` to `RIGHT`.

```
=Right(First(Fields!InvoiceNumber.Value, "InvoiceDataSet"), Len(First(Fields!InvoiceNumber.Value, "InvoiceDataSet"))-3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Chris Albert